# Prompt credentials for single page

Tags: 2013, credentials

I'm now in charge of a SharePoint site, I don't have too much experience with it.

Previous developer set some configuration to prompt for credentials for an specific page, I haven't been able to find where that configuration is, where could that configuration be? other pages don't ask for credentials.

Comment: Which SharePoint Version are you using?

Comment: I'm using sharepoint 2013

Comment: Does the page inherit permissions from the library it's in?

Comment: @ErinL Thanks to your comment I found where the permissions are and then changed them to inherit from its library, if you want you can post that as an answer and I can select it as the correct one, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the page has separate permissions from the library it's in. Try inheriting permissions.